# Creating a framed glass canopy

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Once again I have come to you good people of the Blender community for some help.

I am trying to build a topologically correct aircraft canopy (see pic).  After a couple of days experimenting and about 10 redraws, I am at a total loss on how i can resolve it.  I have been extruding a simple overall shape, then insetting the windows and creating some of the other odd shaped struts.  This usually looks ok until i need to apply subdiv surface then add thickness to the frame.

How would you go about addressing this mesh?  One complete shape or building in say three sections?  How would you go about creating a frame struts with depth?

Many thanks!

[image: My attempts so far]

Comment: in my opinion it makes more sense to use as many meshes as you have parts in the real object. You could have began with some successive extrusions but every one has his own method I guess. At the end, to sharp the angles, put some additional edge loops.

Comment: Out of interest what model aircraft?

Comment: Thanks @moonboots.  I take it I would need to UV unwrap each individual mesh - or would it be feasible to join into a single object then 'U'?

I'm trying to model a Bf 109 G2.

Comment: if you join them in one object but keep distinct meshes, then it would be distinct UV map in the UV Editor

Comment: Great!  I'll give it a go!